# sscanf reading multiple characters

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I am trying to read a list of interfaces given in a config file.

```
 char readList[3];

 memset(readList,'\0',sizeof(readList));

 fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf),fp); //I get the file pointer(fp) without any error

 sscanf(linebuf, "List %s, %s, %s \n",
               &readList[0],
               &readList[1],
               &readList[2]);
```

Suppose the line the config file is something like this 
    list value1 value2 value3

I am not able to read this. Can someone please tell me the correct syntax for doing this. What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/q/9537072/744616

Comment: `char` is a character not a string. You are reading 3 strings into 3 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` conversion specifier in the format string reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters and stores in buffer pointed to by the corresponding argument passed to `sscanf`. The buffer must be large enough to store the input string plus the terminating null byte which is added automatically by `sscanf` else it is undefined behaviour.

```
char readList[3];
```

The above statement defines `readList` to be an array of `3` characters. What you need is an array of characters arrays large enough to store the strings written by `sscanf`. Also the format string `"List %s, %s, %s \n"` in your `sscanf` call means that it must exactly match `"List"` and two commas `'` in that order in the string `linebuf` else `sscanf` will fail due to matching failure. Make sure that you string `linebuf` is formatted accordingly else here is what I suggest. Also, you must guard against `sscanf` overrunning the buffer it writes into by specifying the maximum field width else it will cause undefined behaviour. The maximum field width should be one less than the buffer size to accommodate the terminating null byte.

```
// assuming the max length of a string in linebuf is 40
// +1 for the terminating null byte which is added by sscanf 

char readList[3][40+1];  
fgets(linebuf, sizeof linebuf, fp);

// "%40s" means that sscanf will write at most 40 chars
// in the buffer and then append the null byte at the end.

sscanf(linebuf, 
       "%40s%40s%40s",
       readList[0],
       readList[1],
       readList[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `char readlist[3]` is an array of three chars. What you need however is an array of three strings, like `char readlist[3][MUCH]`. Then, reading them like

```
sscanf(linebuf, "list %s %s %s",
                readList[0],
                readList[1],
                readList[2]);
```

will perhaps succeed. Note that the alphabetic strings in scanf need to match character-by-character (hence `list`, not `List`), and any whitespace in the format string is a signal to skip all whitespace in the string up to the next non-whitespace character. Also note the absence of `&` in `readList` arguments since they are already pointers.