# Is there a better way to avoid null character in c

Tags: c, scanf

On the second iteration of the for loop, there seems to be a null character that is preventing me from inserting my input.
Is there a way to overcome this?

> ```
> # include <stdio.h>
>
> struct student
> {
>     char name[10];
>     int score;
> };
>
> int main()
> {
>     int size = 5;
>     struct student arr[size];
>
>     for (int i = 0; i<size; i++ )
>     {
>         printf("[%d]# Please enter your name ... ",i+1);
>         fgets(arr[i].name,10, stdin);
>
>         printf("\n[%d]# Please insert your score ... ",i+1);
>         scanf("%d",&arr[i].score);
>
>         system("CLS");
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537072/properly-using-sscanf

Comment: Your second scanf leaves a new line `'\n'` character in the standard input (stdin) when you type the score input, the basic solution is to discard it using the specifier `%*c` to read and discard a character, so the scanf would be `scanf("%d%*c",&arr[i].score);` .

Comment: And the `system` function belongs to the `stdlib.h` library so you should include it `#include <stdlib.h>` .